# REGEX Pattern for "PO BOX"

Tags: validation, regular-expressions, validation-rule, errormessages

I have a requirement to create a validation rule on custom object Address_vod__c. There is a picklist field in the object,'Type'. If 'Type' value is not 'mailing' then restrict to create or edit records for below strings.

- PO Box
- Post Office Box
- POBox
- PostOffice Box
- PostOfficeBox
- P.O. Box
- P O Box

*strings are case insensitive

My below code fails for this value:

> Post Office Box Pobox 5500 E 2nd St

Validation Rule :

```
AND(
   OR(REGEX(Name,"\\b(?i)(P *O * B *o *x*)\\b"),
      REGEX(Name,"\\b(P. *O. *Box)\\b")
    ),
    NOT( ISPICKVAL(Address_Type_abv__c,"Mailing"))
)
```

Comment: Personally, I think you're making this harder for yourself than you need to.  I (obviously) don't know your audience, but this sounds like a case where you're better off simplifying it.  Why not validate that the address starts with 'PO Box' or whatever _should_ be the standard, and make the user tweak it accordingly.  This doesn't answer your question, but it does ensure your data is consistent.  That is of course assuming it's user driven, rather than system/integration driven.

Comment: If you stripped out all the dots "." and spaces then converted it lower case you would only need to check that the string contains (or starts with) `pobox` or `postofficebox`

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely go with the following REGEX as it should provide you with the most flexibility and capture case insensitive values as well. In addition, it will capture if they fully write out Post Office Box as well.

```
(?i)\b(?:p\.?\s*o\.?|post\s+office)\s+box\b
```

Answer (score 0):

If read the question, OP is looking for regex validation using a validation rule so the flexibility to reformat the string is not much.

However, I agree with intent of the suggestion by @Nick Cook. Giving more options like this to users,

1) would make them ask for more variations
2) would make it difficult to data cleanse/match
3) would make it difficult if you want to localize

With that said, below regex (validated at [RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/)) seems to work.

```
Po?s?t?\.? ?Of?f?i?c?e?\.? ?Box
```